# What are the Q incapable of doing?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-q

The Q appear to be a race of beings with unlimited power, unified as a single continuum, but powerful enough nonetheless to shape the universe individually.

Yet they seem to have limits - limits that they say Humanity could one day surpass, and limits that allow them to struggle against other powerful foes.

What limits are there to the power of the Q?

**Note:** There are certain things the Q forbid each other from doing - antagonizing the Borg, breaking off from the Continuum, and other things I am sure, but these are things they *should* not do, not things they *can* not do.

I am looking specifically for the latter: things they could not do even if they wanted to and had no restrictions from the Continuum.

Comment: They seem to struggle with the concept of politeness.

Comment: @Richard Perhaps the same could be said of all alien species.

Comment: -that's pretty true in Trek. Everyone seems very keen to shoot first and ask questions later.

Comment: The Q can not spell.

Comment: @BobBrandt maybe that's why Q is so obsesed with Picard - he has a history of being a prolific and skilled teacher in the alphabet.

Comment: They don't seem to be able to overcome the free will or change the personalities of lesser species directly... or it just amuses Q to try doing it indirectly by putting people through fabricated experiences.

Comment: They cannot microwave burritos so hot that they cannot eat them.

Comment: @john - But can they tell it's not butter?

Comment: @Richard More importantly, the Q can see the structure of the universe down to its smallest particles...but can they see the difference in Cinnamon Toast Crunch?

Comment: @JohnO I'm pretty sure that if you microwave your burrito so hot that it vapourizes, it cannot be eaten by anyone, no matter how omnipotent.

Comment: I'm sorely tempted to ask a Q Versus Chuck Norris question...

Comment: Q can't beat Picard and crew...

Comment: Well, the Q can't [square the circle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squaring_the_circle) using a straightedge and a compass.  Such a construction was proven impossible in 1882 as a consequence of the proof that π is a transcendental number.

Comment: @KyleJones Well, when Q was turned into a human, he suggested this solution to a problem (a falling moom iirc): altering the gravitational constant of the universe, so the Q probably *could* square the circle, by temporarily changing π into a non-transcental number.

Comment: They would do anything for love, but they won't do that.

Comment: @BMWurm:  There's a difference between altering physical constants and altering mathematical facts.   One is arbitrary to our universe, the other exists independent of the universe.   The gravitational constant could be anything.   You can't make 4 prime.

Comment: Empathy and courtesy seemed to be beyond the capacity of Q.

Comment: Primarily? Shutting up.

Comment: Preventing the ageing of John DeLancie unfortunately :-(

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Within the TV canon, The Q actually seem pretty limited as supposedly omnipotent beings go. On several occasions we see them [die or suffer serious injury](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Q_Civil_War), make serious errors of judgement in [predicting the intentions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hide_and_Q) of 'lesser beings', they can suffer from evident [depression](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Quinn), they're capable of [removing each other's powers](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Deja_Q_%28episode%29) (when acting in unison) and generally they lack a sense of decorum and politeness.

On top of that, they're identified as having a [limited IQ](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/IQ) (albeit one far in advance of the average human) and a penchant for [petty and vindictive](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/True_Q_%28episode%29) acts of aggression. Q claims that the Q act out of a sense of "Superior Morality" which frankly no-one could possibly accept as true.

As regards their own perceptions of their weaknesses, we can see it in their own words;

> **QUINN:** *But you mustn't think of us as omnipotent, no matter what the Continuum would like you to believe. You and your ship seem
>   incredibly powerful to lifeforms without your technical expertise.
>   It's no different with us. We may appear omnipotent to you, but
>   believe me, we're not.*
>
> **TUVOK:** *Intriguing. Just what vulnerabilities do the Q have?*
>
> **QUINN:** *Always looking for the tactical advantage, Mister Tuvok. Very good. As a matter of fact, that's why I've come to see you. In a
>   way, our vulnerability is what this is all about. As the Q have
>   evolved, we've sacrificed many things along the way. Not just manners,
>   but mortality, and a sense of purpose, and a desire for change, and a
>   capacity to grow. Every loss is a new vulnerability, wouldn't you
>   say?*

Within the [Trek EU canon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek_spin-off_fiction), we see their limitations extremely clearly as Q (or other Qs) are variously trapped in the past, forced to re-attend Q university, turned into statues, turned into swords, turned into pure energy, forced by their peers to mediate planetary disputes, **forced to marry Lwazana Troi** (shudder) and generally treated as the comic relief in a whole host of [comics, books and radio-plays.](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Q)

---

**UPDATE:**

In the IDW comic series "[The Q Gambit, Part 6](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Q_Gambit,_Part_6)", we learn that the Q in fact share their "extra-dimensional space" with the wormhole prophets. After the Pah Wraiths take control of the wormhole, they begin to threaten the Q themselves.

[image]

Comment: A number of those are self-imposed, or imposed upon Q by other Q, could it then be said that Q are perhaps their own greatest enemy, completely vulnerable to their own machinations?

Comment: @Zibbobz - Quite a few of them are imposed externally, for example their relatively low IQ. Why isn't Q's IQ infinite?

Comment: True....I like the quote you added too.  A direct quote from the mouth of a Q that addresses the vulnerabilities he himself sees in his species.

Comment: Q only claimed to have an IQ of 2005 after he had been turned into a human as punishment by the rest of the Continuum, so we don't know if there are limits on their intelligence/knowledge when they have their full powers.

Comment: There is also a big difference between _limited_ and _measurable_. The fact that a particular Q in hi human incarnation had a measurable IQ, does not mean they Q as a race have a _limited_ IQ. Especially since that can be interpreted to mean _low_.

Comment: @Hypnosifl - in one of the books another Q claims to have an IQ of some ridiculously high (but very specific) number like 1000007.

Comment: As far as we can see in the series, Qs are omnipotent, but not omnipresent or omniscience. Time passes linear for them (Q mentions to Janeway that "several years have passed" since they last met (minutes ago for us)), see the beings in the wormhole, which did not know the concept of linear time until Sisko explained it to them. That's a very limiting factor on what they can do or not, because that means that they still have to gather experience, learn things and can not reliable predict the outcome of their actions.

Comment: @Bobby - They seem to have no compunction about advising each other (and themselves) about their future actions. We see this in VOY:"Death Wish".

Answer (score 4):

This is a very subjective question, since you're asking for an answer to something that has never been answered canonically. Any answer would be a product of opinion and conjecture based on the content of the episodes and the spirit in which the viewer takes the byplay between the Q and the humans they interact with.

With that in mind, I think their biggest limitation is understanding. They are all KNOWING and all POWERFUL, but they lack the ability to understand sometimes simple concepts, perhaps showing a lack of actual "life experience".

My basis for this is as follows: when our favourite Q was made mortal in Deja-Q, he struggled to understand the simple concept of selflessness, and couldn't initially understand why Data almost sacrificed himself to save him. New Q (the one played by Corbin Bernsen in the same episode) commented on the limitations of the human form but showed SOME understanding of compassion.

They seem to be created as functioning adult entities but with a childish mind and attitudes. Humanity's greatness (in relation to the Q) is that humanity has built on what it has learned and developed socially as well as intellectually, and in that has far bypassed the Q - that's why Q keeps coming back to Picard and Janeway: to learn and to increase his learning through his human teachers.

It's easy to philosophise about the role that Q and humanity play against each other, but I think the simplest way to see it is that the Q see themselves as superior to humans, but humans do not see themselves as superior to the Q - and THAT's the biggest lesson the Q have still to learn - humility.

It's possible their ability to do things will / can increase as the individual Q ages intellectually. So maybe the older and more wise the Q becomes the more he/she discovers about his/her power and the more can be done.

Comment: It's very clear that the Q aren't "all knowing". They regularly fail to predict the actions of others around them.