# Are the Q and the Douwd aware of each other?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-q

Amanda Rogers' parents (who were Q) and the Douwd known as Kevin, were on earth pretending to be humans at the same time. Given their powers, it does seem likely they were aware of each other.

So are Q and Douwd aware of each other?

Comment: This seems highly speculative, not least because they were on different planets. My guess is that if Q cared enough to have done a census of the entire human race, he'd instantly have identified Kevin as a non-human

Comment: They were on earth at the same time, that's where Kevin met his wife, and where Amanda Rogers parents lived

Comment: I'm still hung up on why you'd think that Q would care?

Comment: A being that is potentially equal to the Q, Doing exactly the same thing they are doing, they would be curious of each other

Comment: The Douwd are inferior to the Q. The episodes definitely show this.

Comment: @T-1000'sSon not necessarily, the douwd were almost if not at the same level as Q

Comment: @Darren: “not necessarily, the douwd were almost if not at the same level as Q” — it might help if you could support that.

Comment: No reason not to support seeing what they are capable of

Comment: If the Kevin were as powerful as Q, he could have gone back in time and wiped out the Husnock before they even achieved warp capability, or destroyed their ships. He could have brought back his wife from the dead for real as opposed to just an illusion, he could have just "pushed" them into the Beta Quadrant like Q did to the Enterprise. There are several non-lethal abilities Q demonstrates that Kevin should have used first that could have saved his wife. While powerful, Kevin is not a powerful as Q

Comment: Maybe not but I believe a lot of Q powers are illusions, even Quinn said there not omnipotent it just appears that way, maybe Kevin does not try to make out he is omnipotent  and has no shame in admiting  he can't do somethings

Comment: @Darren - There are no indications that the Q's powers are illusory and it's been [reasonably well confirmed](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/82248/are-the-douwd-related-to-the-q) that the Q are dramatically superior to the Douwd.

Comment: There are things the Q can't do which questions there power to a degree

Comment: @darren - The only [real limits](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/52073/20774) to the power of the Q seems to be that they cannot override a larger number of Q. Beyond that, they are (for all intents) omnipotent and omniscient.

Comment: They can't commit suicide, or bring dead Q ' s back to life

Comment: @darren - Quinn is *prevented* from committing suicide. Note his surprise when it doesn't work.

Comment: No he simply can't do it, and he couldent escape the confines of the comet

Comment: @darren - again, he is prevented from escaping by a larger number of Q. 2 Q can make a box that one Q can't escape

Comment: Well could Q bring Quinn back to life

Comment: @Darren - We don't know. My guess is "yes", but with the caveat that once the deed was done, the rift that his death caused was presumably unfixable, hence there would be little point resurrecting someone with a suicidal personality.

Comment: @Richard Quinn's "surprise" at his suicide not working could instead be because all the male crew members disappeared. As for all Q being omnipotent and omniscient, Quinn was unable to return the male crew to Voyager while Q could. There is just too much we don't know about the Q, individually or as a group, to say that there is nothing they can't do.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### Full canon

The short answer is that **we don't know.** There is only one mention of the Douwd in the TNG series (in [Survivors](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Survivors_(episode))) and no further mentions of them in any canon property including the other TV series, films or canon 'ongoing' comics.

### Extended universe

Moving down the food chain into the EU novels and comics, the answer is **we don't know**. There are only the most glancing references to the Douwd in any of the Extended Universe novels, and always only in the sense of "*powerful beings like* x" (where x is the name of a being such as the Organians, the Q or the Douwd)".

### Pure guesswork

**We don't know.** Certainly the Douwd are very powerful which potentially makes them interesting to the Q. The flipside is that they may have sufficient power to somehow hide themselves from the Q. I lean toward the fact that the Q known as Quinn makes it abundantly clear (in Voy: Deathwish) that the Q have **been everywhere and seen everything**. That presumably would include knowing everything about the Douwd that there is to know.

Comment: Agreed, great answer

Comment: @Darren - Around these parts, if you say "I don't know", you better be damn sure you show why you don't know :-)

Comment: This truly is a "we don't know" answer.

Comment: The Q are fairly well-known for their hubris, so I wouldn't really take the quote from Deathwish at face value. They certainly have enough arrogance to *believe* they've gone everywhere and seen/know everything, without *actually* having done it.

Answer (score -1):

Logically, both the Q and and the Douwd must be aware of one another as they both exhibit omniscience. If a Douwd could destroy every Husnock individual in creation, he would need the trait of omniscience.

Q is able to manifest at will across spacetime in any direction (All Good Things...) which also implies an ability to 'omnisce.' There is literally nothing he cannot observe anywhere or anywhen at any time.

On the other hand, just because these entities CAN know everything, doesn't mean they DO know everything. They can also choose NOT to seek out knowledge, in theory.

And is it also possible that a 'greater omnipotent-omniscient' could cloak itself from a 'lesser omnipotent?' Maybe... But regardless of whether the Q Rogers were aware of their proximity to Kevin Uxbridge, the Q Continuum likely know of the Douwd and vice versa.

**But the original question begs a larger question:**

In 'Encounter at Farpoint' and 'True Q', Q makes it clear that the Continuum consider themselves to be moral superiors. One aspect of this is their restraint from abuse of their powers. They, like the Organians hold themselves to be the judges of 'lesser' races.

So if the Q or Organians would judge Terrans for their historical wars, it seems odd that they haven't dropped the hammer on Kevin Uxbridge, if they are indeed superior to the Douwd. So either:

1. **The Q are less powerful than the Douwd:** and can do nothing to them. (Kevin maintains that he is immortal and cannot be destroyed).
2. **The Q are coequal to the Douwd**, and can do nothing to them.
3. **The Q are more powerful than the Douwd**, and CHOOSE not to hold them to account. If this is so, then it implies all their threats against humanity could well be hollow and calculated solely for effect. All we really know is that they are willing to exact capital punishment on their own, as they kill Amanda Rogers' Q parents for abusing their powers.

So the ultimate question may be: **Can the'Galactic Gods of the Milky Way police each other?'**

If Kevin Uxbridge decides one day he want to blow up the Milky Way, would the Q have anything to say about it and vice versa?  The Q enforce law against their own, but the Douwd clearly have done nothing against Kevin.

While the Organians, Q, and Douwd demonstrate very 'strong wills' to resist the death impulse that might lead them to blow up the universe they are AWOL when their coequals go off the rails.

**Proof**: the Q civil war blows up a number of star systems. Neither the Douwd nor the Organians intervene.

The Douwd genocide of the Husnock. Neither the Q nor the Organians intervene.

So this suggests that the same tenuous balance of power that exists between nuclear powers also scales up to a stalemate amongst these 'omnipotents' as well.

I think these 'Omni's' must be quite aware of each other but seem powerless to intervene against one another or are afraid to play the galactic finger wagging game with one another as they do with lesser species. Perhaps such a conflict would be even more disastrous.

But given that existence is just a state of quantum possibilities that these omnipotents can traverse at will, maybe creating one universe where the Husnock disappear, while continuing to exist in an infinite number of other universes means that these beings really don't take existence too seriously.

Kevin Uxbridge's guilt, therefore, like his pacifism, is a pure affectation.  He could just as easily have recreated the Husnock as destroyed them and maybe he will in the future when he has paid his penance and none will be the wiser. Maybe the Q know this and have moved on. And his interaction with the Enterprise is just a kabuki object lesson for their benefit and his own self-flagellation.

Comment: Neither the Q nor the Douwd have omniscience. The Q are terrified of what might happen if one of their number chooses to die and Kevin was taken in by a simple ruse.

Comment: True that they don't know what will happen per se. Also, omnipotence and omniscience are mutually exclusive. However, they may have quasi-omniscience. 1) If the future is the set of all quantum possibilities, they can 'omnisciently' foresee them all without simultaneously knowing what will actually prevail. Though they could statistically have a strong idea. 2) They are telepathic and can spy on people anytime anywhere.  3) Immortality + time travel= the ability to know everything. 4) The upshot is they have to actively use these abilities to master the situation. They may or may not.

Comment: TV writers have to crank out stories which may or not make sense in the grand scheme. My 'no prize' theory is that though Kevin is likely capable enough to divine Picard's intentions at any time, (He does exhibit some power to reach into minds, though maybe only to create illusions)  he subconsciously wants to confess his sins and thus 'allows' them to discover his crime. You can't repent if you've no confessor. To the point of the post: I think the Q would notice the Husnock's disappearance and be alerted to the Douwd if not before. Unless Kevin wiped them from the minds of all other beings?